# How to do an infinitely extending text effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typography

[image]

I'm looking to create a similar-style text effect to what is in the image.
Mainly, I want the extended rainbow effect coming off the backside of the text.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE - please take a quick look around [tour] and [ask] and [answer] a question, to get an idea of our community and the kinds of questions which are appropriate here, and how to frame them in order to encourage the best responses. One thing we like to see is what you've tried so far to achieve your desire results, and where that effort has met trouble. Can you edit to show your current efforts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make as many texts copies as colors the gradient will have

- The bottom-left text has the same color as the background
- Arrange them from back to front, from bottom to top

[image: texts]

Select all the texts and go to menu **Object** → **Blend** → **Make**

[image: Blend]

Select the blend and go to menu **Object** → **Blend** → **Blend options** and change the **Spacing** number to **Specified Steps**:

[image: Spacing]

Put the original white text on top

[image: End]